# Manually check server's certificate using HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-8, certificate

I am using `HttpWebRequest` to work with service's https API, now I need to check https certificate manually on client side (Windows Phone 8 application), how could I do it?

I have got `certificate.cert` file, so I can put it to the `Assets` folder and then compare it to the server's certificate, but I do not know how

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have read some tutorials about manually checking `SSL` certificates in `.NET` using [`ServicePointManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx), and when I started implement it in Windows Phone 8 application, I realized that `.NET` Framework for WP8 (and 7) just has not got API to handle SSL certificates validating. We just can't have access to [`ServicePointManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx)...

Then I found this post: ["Self Signed Certification SSL HTTPS" on wpdev.uservoice.com](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1930835-self-signed-certification-ssl-https), where developers are asking Microsoft to add this API into next WP SDK updates, of course I have spent my 3 votes on that, so if you want to see `ServicePointManager` in WP .NET framework, please vote for that.

Also, I want to notice you about strange behavior of `HttpWebRequest` on WP, when you trying to work with self-signed https resource, `HttpWebRequest` will throw `404 exception`! Very strange, yes?

Comment: You ruined my dreams! Now it's 3rd party library time :/ Thanks for the information BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I use a commercial library that you can test. Its possible to read server certificates! I had a similiar question about certificates and WP8.

[Read SSL Certificate Details on WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741740/read-ssl-certificate-details-on-wp8)

Regards
Holger