# Display ssl-certificate details in WebControl inside Windows Phone app

Tags: ssl, windows-phone-8, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to retrieve and possibly validate a certificate used on a web page displayed in a WebControl in a Windows Phone app?

Inside the WebControl I display a web page over ssl (https), which has a trusted verisign certificate. I want to give the user the option to display detailed information about the certificate as well as displaying it as EV-SSL certificate - that is when you display the organization name.

I want to give the user a feeling of trust through certificate information, like issuer, organization, certificate used - pretty much the same way google chrome on iOS does.

Comment: Maybe you can use a WebBrowserTask instead of an embedded WebControl? The thing is, even if there was a way to display the information about the certificate, I don't think it would give much reassurance to the user. You're in your application's context, you could display whatever information you want and just mimic the system dialog (if there was one), how could the user tell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read SSL Certificate Details on WP8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741740/read-ssl-certificate-details-on-wp8)