# Windows Phone 8.0 certificate pinning

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8

How i can do certificate pinning in Windows Phone 8.0 without commercial libraries like SecureBlackbox? 
I can do it for Windows Phone 8.1, but it doesn't work for WP8.0.

Code for WP8.1

```
private async Task<bool> GetPublicKeysFromServer(string serverUrl)
    {
        //clear old cers
        serverPublicKyes = new List<string>();

        Uri serverUri = new Uri(serverUrl);
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        string responseData = string.Empty;
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response = await httpClient.GetAsync(serverUri);

        List<Certificate> listCerts = new List<Certificate>();
        listCerts.Add(response.RequestMessage.TransportInformation.ServerCertificate);

        foreach (Certificate aCertificate in listCerts)
        {
            IBuffer buffer = aCertificate.GetCertificateBlob();
            byte[] bCert = buffer.ToArray();
            string scert = BitConverter.ToString(bCert);
            byte[] rsaOID = EncodeOID("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1");//1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
            string sOID = BitConverter.ToString(rsaOID);
            int length;
            int index = FindX509PubKeyIndex(bCert, rsaOID, out length);
            // Found X509PublicKey in certificate so copy it.
            if (index > -1)
            {
                byte[] X509PublicKey = new byte[length];
                Array.Copy(bCert, index, X509PublicKey, 0, length);
                string URLCertPublicKey = BitConverter.ToString(X509PublicKey);
                serverPublicKyes.Add(URLCertPublicKey);
                Debug.WriteLine("Site Cert: " + URLCertPublicKey);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

WP8.0 API does not support:

[Windows.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography(v=win.10).aspx)
and
[HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.transportinformation(v=win.10).aspx)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code you have tried?

Comment: added my code for WP8.1

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: WP8.0 doesn't support HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation

Answer (score -1):

For Windows Phone 8/8.1: [Certificate pinning on windows phone 8/8.1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/849510/Certificate-Pinning-on-Windows-Phone)

I don't think you can do it without using commercial library as you mentioned. You should give it a try. If not then here I found some content from Stack Overflow itself ([Read SSL Certificate Details on WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741740/read-ssl-certificate-details-on-wp8)):

> For WP8, you can use the StreamSocket class, which has an
>   UpgradeToSslAsync() method that will do the TLS handshake for you as
>   an async operation. Once that completes, you can use the
>   .Information.ServerCertificate property to check that you got the
>   server certificate you were expecting.

Comment: it's work for WP8.1, but WP8.0 doesn't support HttpRequestMessage.TransportInformation

Comment: .Information.ServerCertificate available only from WP8.1 [ServerCertificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketinformation.servercertificate.aspx)